# Can I still get a license for Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I have a netbook that came with a trial version of MS office 2007.  I used up the free trial in January.  Now I want to convert to a regular license.  When I clicked on "Convert" it sent me to Microsoft's website, which sent me to Digital River.  For some reason, I was unable to sign up with digital River.

Is it still possible to convert 2007 to a regular license?  (It's the Home and Student edition).  Will I have to upgrade to Officec 2010 instead?  Can I install 2010 on a computer that has no CD reader inboard?  Is Digital River the right vendor for me to deal with, given that I'm buying for  home use?

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HCZ8EO) still sells a full license to Microsoft Office Home And Student 2007. Since its no longer being sold by Microsoft I would just upgrade to Office 2013. Both Office 2010 and Office 2013 have seamless online installers.

I am sure other online retailers have an Microsoft Office Home And Student 2007 license for sale just take your pick.